# Footer does not move to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

today I've been trying to work out a footer, I've been trying to do this through CSS, but it wouldn't move to the bottom, whatever I tried. This is what I have currently:

```css
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>TEST TEKST</p>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: Depending on your html declarations you might need to add a rule for `html,body {height: 100%}`

Comment: try #footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0; }

Comment: can you show more from your code

Comment: I use Google Chrome 68.

Comment: May we have link ?

Comment: put your code in https://jsfiddle.net/ and let us know the link

Comment: @vicbyte That seemed to work and fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Robinblitz take a look of `fixed` support:https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: @Robinblitz, Accept the answer if it worked for you rather than thank you please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without seeing your entire html its difficult to be sure but you need to declare height: 100% on the body & html also your footer maybe inside an element that has position: relative; meaning that your footer will position to the bottom of that element.

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>TEST TEKST</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This was indeed the issue. What I had was:

body {
min-height: 100%;
}

I forgot the "html, " before that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

position absolute always depends upon its ancestor (position relative), but if has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

try putting your div#footer directly inside the body

```
<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>
      TEST TEKST
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

and also add left property to your css to prevent it to overlap its ancestor

```
#footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;    //<----
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color:   red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any content before your footer so DOM only have one element i.e. footer so bottom: 0px will not do the work. If you have only one element in DOM and you want its position w.r.t to your window size try giving values in "vh" to fix it position depending on your window size. here is the updated snippet.
hope that's what you are looking for

```css
#footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>TEST TEKST</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 100% height to your HTML too

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Also, you could have your footer to display:fixed; so that is always at the bottom of your page (if the page has a scroll).

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Finally for best practice, change your footer from an ID to a Class. (in CSS change # to .).